# How can I translate this pseudocode into React/javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to start using my cities.txt file which has 15k city names separated by newlines as a quick database to show the first three matches. I wrote some Python pseudocode of what I'm trying to accomplish but can't figure out how to do it in js? Thanks

````
     // look through cities.txt and show first 3 results that start with e.target.value
     const searchbarChanged = e => {
        // open cities.txt as cityfile
        // listoflines = cityfile.readlines()
        // for (let i = 0; i<listoflines.length; i++){
            // results = []
            // count = 0
            // if (listoflines[i].startswith(e.target.value) && count!=3)
                // put in results
                // count++
        // }
        // console.log(results)
     }```
````

Comment: Is this something you will run on node, or in a browser environment?

Comment: This is running on a browser environment @JeroenBourgois

Comment: Take a look at using a FileReader https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#APIASynch

Comment: I read it, but I don't see any file reading ability, it looks like it asks to put the text file as a Blob, but when I read the documentation on Blob https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob , there's no way to turn a text file into a Blob value in the first place!

Comment: What server side technology are you using? PHP, Elixir, Python,...? You could read the file there and output it as json in the markup, read it there or provide an api to access it through a http call?

Comment: It's pure front end. HTML, CSS, JS/React.